# Pybind11: casting custom python type to custom C++ ptr

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Trying to make python bindings for c++ function.
Function takes path and an object of custom type pT.

```
.def("myFunc", [](myClass &self, py::args args){
    std::string path;
    path = py::str(args[0]);

    mySmartPtr *cls = args[1].cast<mySmartPtr *>();
    return self.myFunc(path, *cls);
})
```

It compiles fine, at runtime gives error:
`Unable to cast Python instance of type <pT> to C++ type 'std::shared_ptr<myClass>'`

Have tried casting in different way:
`mySmartPtr &cls = py::cast<mySmartPtr &>(args[1]);`
It gives same error.

And:

```
py::object obj = args[1];
std::dynamic_pointer_cast<mySmartPtr> (obj);
```

Gives error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'dynamic_pointer_cast(pybind11::object&)'
note:   'pybind11::object' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>'
```

Following docs, tried to extract PyObject direcly via:
`PyObject *cls = args[1].ptr();`
It crashes at runtime with message: "Segmentation fault".

This Python type pT is perfectly convertible into c++ type.
Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Solved, need to inform pybind that mySmartPtr is derived from another base cpp class.

`py::class_<Derived, std::shared_ptr<Derived>, Base>(m, "Derived").def(py::init<>());`

This issue was very helpful:
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1705